# Не могу авторизоваться в http запросе

Tags: веб-программирование, http, request, postman, httpwebrequest

Есть аккаунт на сайте https://naurok.com.ua. Я авторизуюсь, затем перехожу по ссылке [/test/test-po-filosofii-541029/flashcard](https://naurok.com.ua/test/test-po-filosofii-541029/flashcard).

После того, как я перешёл по ссылке, она подгружает карточки через запрос [/api/test/documents/541029/flashcard](https://naurok.com.ua/api/test/documents/541029/flashcard). **Его мне нужно успешно отправить:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я тестирую через Postman запрос [api/test/documents/541029/flashcard](https://naurok.com.ua/api/test/documents/541029/flashcard). Он посылается с захваченными Cookie, однако он говорит, что необходимо авторизоваться на сайте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему на сайте всё работает, а через мой запрос - нет?** Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Дополнительно захватывание куки на странице https://naurok.com.ua/test/test-po-filosofii-541029/flashcard, перед основным запросом не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо зарубежной версии Stack Overflow, там мне подсказали, что проблема в том, что сайту нужен заголовок Referer.